# "svelte-kit dev" command not creating an index.html file while build

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit, svelte-component, svelte-store

I'm trying to create a `svelte app` using `svelte-kit`. And I'm having an internal larval server where I'm using the build folder for opening the `index.html` file.

But the problem is for every time I am doing a change I have to do the `svelte-kit build`.

And initially, the `svelte-kit build` also does not create the index.html. So, we configure some adapters to overcome this issue.

I want the same behavior while running the `svelte-kit dev` also. I don't know what are configurations I needed to change. Currently while I run dev it creates `.svelte-kit` folder.

```
// svelte.config.js file
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

const config = {
kit: {
    adapter: adapter(),
    
    // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
    target: '#svelte',

    vite: {
        optimizeDeps: {
            include: ['just-throttle', 'dayjs']
        }
    }

   },
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Do you still have the file `src/app.html` in your project. If it's the case and you use sveltekit `v1.0.0-next.174` then it should create the index file (just tested).

Comment: Yes, I have an app.html file. Will check it.

Comment: I was currently using 1.0.0-next.199. Is there anything I need to work on this version? Like some config changes in svelte.config.js

Comment: yes, adding to config.kit prerender : { default: true} made index.html appear in my case